# Popup disappears while selecting options from ListBox<String>

Tags: java, gwt

I have a popup in GWT UI screen, in that popup I have Listbox. My problem is when I try to select any option in the ListBox popup closes itself and all I can see is ListBox dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

PopupPanel have autoHide function in default.

Use below code to disable autoHide when creating PopupPanel.

```
PopupPanel myPopUp = new PopupPanel(false);
```

Use these methods to handle open and close PopupPanel.

```
myPopUp.show();
myPopUp.hide();
```